# Max file number can php upload at same time

Tags: php, file, upload, numbers

I am using the tag 
for uploading multiple files with php. I notice that if i choose more than 20 files php uploads only the first 20 files.Is there a way to expand this limit?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This limit was added in [PHP 5.2.12](https://www.php.net/releases/5_2_12.php), to avoid a type of DOS attack: temporary files exhaustion.

Changelog of PHP 5.2.12:

> Added "max_file_uploads" INI directive, which can be set to limit the number of file uploads per-request to 20 by default, to prevent possible DOS via temporary file exhaustion, identified by Bogdan Calin. (CVE-2009-4017, Ilia)

You can increase this limit by changing the [`max_file_uploads`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads) directive.

Answer (score 2):

The size of total upload is limited and not the number of files. You can change the total size by editing this line in `php.ini`:

```
   post_max_size = 256M
```

Or more. So, if you want to upload 50 files, each of 100 MB, then you should set this limit more than 5000 MB.

Comment: +1, this setting is very important. On PHP 5.3.1+ even if you have `max_file_uploads` directive set to a bigger number(default 20) to allow more uploads in a request, without an increase in `post_max_size` directive, the total size of files may exceed allowed limit and will fail. So, this solution along with [@artefacto's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3565221/1369473) will give the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

I think that is not 20 limit fault, but php config post_max_size and upload_max_filesize or bad handling of your upload form. Can you show us a sample source of your form and handling ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the max_file_uploads permission and upload_max_filesize in php.ini file.

You may add this line in php.ini file.

```
max_file_uploads=100
upload_max_filesize = 500M
```

Comment: This answer is redundant. The selected answer already gives the reply.

Answer (score -4):

see `upload_max_filesize` in **php.ini**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11333488)

Comment: @sebastianbrosch This looks like an *attempt* at an answer. If you think this is wrong or incomplete, you can downvote it. Don't misuse the LQPRQ for deletion of such posts.

Comment: @ArtjomB. - thats low quality and should be a comment!

Comment: @sebastianbrosch Please read the description for **not an answer** (no attempt at an answer) and **very low quality** (gibberish). Also, this might help: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/266187)