# Maximum number of files being uploaded by input type file

Tags: php, html, file-upload, types, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Max file number can php upload at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564796/max-file-number-can-php-upload-at-same-time)

I'm trying to upload multiple files using html and php

```
<input type="file" name="upload[]" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, application/x-tar, application/x-zip-compressed"  multiple="true">
```

in php when using

```
print count($_FILES['upload']);
```

I always get maximum 5 files even if I've selected 20 in html.
What should I do to be able to upload, let's say, 20 files at a time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564796/max-file-number-can-php-upload-at-same-time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may need to change in php.ini file and increase the limit of `max_file_uploads` (it mustbe 5 in your server now)

Also make sure to make relevant changes to these parameters (if needed)

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
max_input_time
max_execution_time
```

---

**LevSahakyan solved the problem.**

He was using

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']); $i++)
```

and because 'upload' is an array itself and has 5 parameters (name, type, tmp_name, error and  size) it was uploading only 5 items.
now he is using right parameter -

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++)
```

Comment: I have checked everything you mentioned, but no way :(

Comment: Make sure that these settings are not changed elsewhere. In IIS there is a web.config, in Apache there is httpd.config. check for LimitRequestBody 

Also check .htaccess file

PS
After making changes in php.ini you must restart your server too :)

Comment: Nik, I'm using wamp on my local computer, just no way :) and btw I have the same problem on web server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change these 2 parameters in php.ini file in order to allow this.

```
max_file_uploads = 20
post_max_size = 256M
```

This will allow you to upload 20 files at the same time, and also increase the maximum allowance for the upload file size.

Comment: I have that parameters correct, but no way :(