# only 20 images are uploaded

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to upload  100 images but I only got 20 image uploaded? 
Could someone tell me what's wrong with my code below ?

HTML code:

```
  <input type="file" name="filepic[]" multiple/>
```

PHP code:

```
         foreach ($_FILES ['filepic']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
{
    echo $fileNamei  = $_FILES ['filepic']['name'][$key];
    $fileSize  = $_FILES ['filepic']['size'][$key];
    $fileTmp   = $_FILES ['filepic']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $fileType  = $_FILES ['filepic']['type'][$key];
    $partnerNum  = rtrim($fileNamei, ".jpg");

    $img = rtrim($fileNamei, ".jpg");
    $imgName = $img.'-'.$batchnumber.'.jpg'; 
    $dir = "../../Libraries/PenImage";
    move_uploaded_file ($fileTmp, "$dir/".$imgName);    

    $partner    = $partnerNum;
    $batchnum   = $batchnumber; 
    $uplDate    = $uplDatep;
    $timeUpl    = $timeup;
    $fileName   = $imgName;
    $fileSize   = $fileSize;
    $fileType   = $fileType;

    if ($partnerNum)
    { 
       $inserPic = $obj ->insertImage($partner, $batchnum, $uplDate, $timeUpl, $fileName, $fileSize, $fileType);
    }
     //error = validation
$picerr = array();
$errNotification = false;

  if (!$partnerNum)
{
    $picerr[] = 'NO Pensioner/s Image Uploaded';
    $errNotification = true;
}

if ($errNotification)
{
    $_SESSION['imgErr'] = $picerr;
    header('location:../../Pages/Uploading/uploadImageupdate.php');
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and then consider revising your question.

Comment: thanks @TiesonT. for the grammar and corrections

Comment: Your post was edited by @Begueradj, not me.

Comment: Have u tries this answer given in this post regarding max_file_uploads directive  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564796/max-file-number-can-php-upload-at-same-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php.ini is restricting to max 20 POST elements. Change `max_file_uploads=20` to higher value.

Comment: trying to look for it in php.ini is it the same for upload_max_filesize = 20M i already change it to 1024m

Comment: @FranzJosephMendoza it will increase max size of file only (so if you have files not grater than 20M, no need to change). Also you can change `max_execution_time` to allow script to execute longer.

Comment: ok got it sir... i write in on my php.ini it is strange that it is not there thank you so much