# Limit number of files that can be uploaded

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How can I limit the number of files that can be uploaded?

The `max` validation seems to apply to the size of the image (in kilobytes). How can I make a validation for the maximum number of files allowed to be uploaded (for example, only 10 files can be uploaded from a single input)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max file number can php upload at same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564796/max-file-number-can-php-upload-at-same-time)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of that. I'm asking how to create a validation WITHIN LARAVEL that limits the number of files that can be uploaded and show a message if it's over that limit.

Comment: Don't think Laravel has a built-in validation rule for that. Many js upload plugins can set such limit but in the end you need to provide custom backend validation. Also, this might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In laravel, there is no built-in validation rule for that. But you can create [custom-validation rule](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules) to handle this.

Here is a simple custom-validation rule for it.

Create `customValidator.php` in `app/` directory.

```
Validator::extend('upload_count', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{   
    $files = Input::file($parameters[0]);

    return (count($files) <= $parameters[1]) ? true : false;
});
```

Don't forget to add it to `app/start/global.php`

```
require app_path().'/customValidator.php';
```

In your validation setting,

```
$messages = array(
    'upload_count' => 'The :attribute field cannot be more than 3.',
);

$validator = Validator::make(
    Input::all(),
    array('file' => array('upload_count:file,3')), // first param is field name and second is max count
    $messages
);

if ($validator->fails()) {
     // show validation error
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 9):

How I did in laravel 7.x

Create a new form request class with the following command

> php artisan make:request UploadImageRequest

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\BaseFormRequest;

class UploadImageRequest extends BaseFormRequest
{
public function authorize()
{
  return true;
}

public function rules()
{
  return [
    'coverImage.*' => 'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    'coverImage' => 'max:5',
  ];
} 

public function messages() {
  return [
    'coverImage.*.max' => 'Image size should be less than 2mb',
    'coverImage.*.mimes' => 'Only jpeg, png, bmp,tiff files are allowed.',
    'coverImage.max' => 'Only 5 images are allowed'
  ];
}
```

in View.blade.php

```
<input type="file" id="coverImage" name="coverImage[]"
                        class="form-control-file @error('coverImage') is-invalid @enderror" multiple>                        
@error('coverImage')
 <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
@enderror
```

in controller

```
public function store(UploadImageRequest $request)
{
  //code
}
```