# How to validation number of files

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

How to validation number of files.
I find many way and read alot of topic. But i can't found this result.
I found only validation files size.

```
'files' => 'size:2560|max:2560'
```

All of this only files size.
How can I know number of files.

Answer (score 3):

if your files is an array **max** checks array length.

```
'files' => 'max:5' //maximum number of files: 5

'files.*' => 'max:5' //maximum size of each file: 5kb
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no default rule for the number of files. However, you can write a custom rule for validation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-file

Please have a look here for a sample on implementation for the same.

[Limit number of files that can be uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087560/limit-number-of-files-that-can-be-uploaded)