# Validate max number of multiple files that can be attached in Laravel Validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, file-upload

I have a form that allows multiple files to be attached.

I am validating the form for attachment field as:

```
$this->validate($request, [

            'attachments.*' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png|max:5000',
        ]);
```

It works properly but I also want to only allow maximum of 3 files to be uploaded at a time.

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: You need to add custom rule for this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As `attachments` is an array, you can use `max` rule to validate it max elements as `3`

```
 $messages = [
    "attachments.max" => "file can't be more than 3."
 ];

 $this->validate($request, [

        'attachments.*' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png|max:5000',
        'attachments' => 'max:3',
    ],$messages);
```

Comment: Ok that's working but the error says:The attachments may not be greater than 3 characters. So how can I give my own custom message for this ?

Comment: @Raj -`Naam to suna hoga` : Have updated with custom message.

Comment: Not working, It indicates the maximum size instead of the number of uploaded files.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore for Laravel 8.

Answer (score 3):

There is option to add [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules) in laravel.

Also you can try something like this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'attachments.*' => [
        'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png',
        function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (count($value) > 3) {
                return $fail($attribute . ' should be less than or equal to 3.');
            }
        },
    ]
]);
```

There is another solution posted here: [How to validation number of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328265/how-to-validation-number-of-files)

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best way is to create a new validation rule.

As per `Laravel 8` I managed this way:

1- Created a new rule executing this command:

`php artisan make:rule UploadCount`

2- Go find new rule `UploadCount.php` under `app/Rules` and paste this:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{

    return (count($value) <= 5) ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Get the validation error message.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function message()
{
    if ( \Config::get('app.locale') == 'en') {
        return 'You cannot upload more than 5 images';
    } else {
        return 'Non puoi caricare piu di 5 immagini';
    }

}
```

If you can see in my case the limit is 5 files but you can change it.

P.S. I did not removed `if statement` from `message()` method because someone may need it to have different messages in case of localization otherwise you can use `lang` folder with automatic messages. In case your project is not multilang you can just:

`return 'You cannot upload more than 5 images';`

3- Now on your form request you should:

Import `UploadCount`: `use App\Rules\UploadCount;`.

and:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'images'            => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:32768',
        'images'            => [new UploadCount()],
    ];
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: `return count($value) <= 5;`

Comment: Thnx you're right