# In Laravel how can I validate the count of multiple file upload

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.4

In my project I have a multiple file upload, where user can upload pictures not more than 3 and not less than 3. How can I validate this?

```
<input id="institute_pics" type="file" class="form-control" name="institute_pics[]" multiple>


institute_pics' => 'required|max:3|min:3' //not working
```

Comment: How you setup your `database table` and `controller`?

Comment: Solution for your question.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29093913/5350773

Comment: @ZaheerAttar thank you :-)

Comment: You are most welcome

Comment: in laravel 7.x [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63102392/8843433](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63102392/8843433)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting min first

```
institute_pics' => 'required|min:3|max:3'
```