# File Button using loops

Tags: php, html

I have som doubt in the following code.

**file.php**

```
<form method="post" action="Filesave.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
   for($i=0;$i<25;$i++) {
?>
   <input type="file" id="f[]" name="f[]">
<?php
   }
?>
   <br />
   <br />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**filesave.php**

```
<?php
   for($i=0;$i<25;$i++) {
      $image = $_FILES["f"]["name"][$i];
      $filepath = $_FILES['f']['tmp_name'][$i];
      echo($i." Image Name ".$image." File Path ".$filepath."<br>");
   }
?>
```

In the above code after 20th iteration the following error will be displayed.

> Notice: Undefined offset: 20 in C:\wamp\www\IMGUpload\Filesave.php on line 4
>       Notice: Undefined offset: 20 in C:\wamp\www\IMGUpload\Filesave.php on line 5

Please tell how to solve this problem?

Comment: File.php
--------
<form method="post" action="Filesave.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
for($i=0;$i<25;$i++)
{
?>
<input type="file" id="f[]" name="f[]">
<?php
}
?>
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
Filesave.php
------------
<?php
for($i=0;$i<25;$i++)
{
$image = $_FILES["f"]["name"][$i];
$filepath = $_FILES['f']['tmp_name'][$i];
echo($i." Image Name ".$image." File Path ".$filepath."<br>");
}
?>

Comment: Please edit your post with your code rather than posting as a comment.

Comment: can you please add full code

Comment: I have edit the comment with code. please refer the above code and give the solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're looping through 26 indexes in $_FILES['f'] where the case could've been that you only uploaded 19 images (i.e 19 indexes).
Since the images that could be uploaded are variable, you need to use the count() function to determine how many images are sent for uploading.

**filesave.php**

```
$image_count = count($_FILES['f']['tmp_name']);
for($i=0;$i<$image_count-1;$i++) {
  $image = $_FILES["f"]["name"][$i];
  $filepath = $_FILES['f']['tmp_name'][$i];
  echo($i." Image Name ".$image." File Path ".$filepath."<br>");
}
```

Comment: Only 20 images are uploaded at a time?

Comment: Nope, you can upload as many files you want. Just remember to use `count()` to  get the number of files uploaded by the user.

Comment: I tried that. but the count value is 20. when i am try to upload 25 images.

Comment: My bad, the default max limit is 20. You can increase it, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564796/max-file-number-can-php-upload-at-same-time