# Upload two images from two different input fields to database with PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to upload two files from two different input fields into two different folders but something is going wrong. Please check my rough code.

html form:

```
   <input type="file" name="pp" placeholder="profile pic" />
   <input type="file" name="proof" placeholder="id proof"/>
```

these are my form fields

Here, I took file names and paths to upload in two different folders 'id' and 'pp'

```
     $path = "uploads/id/";
     $path2 = "uploads/pp/";
     $pp = $_FILES['pp']['name'];
     $pp1 = $path2 . basename(time().$_FILES['pp']['name']);


     $proof = $_FILES['proof']['name'];
     $proof1 = $path . basename(time().$_FILES['proof']['name']);
```

here is the code to move uploaded files.

```
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pp']['tmp_name'],$path2.$pp) ;
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['proof']['tmp_name'],$path.$proof);
```

I am getting an error, I can only upload one file at a time, not two files. Please someone help me where this going wrong?

Comment: Take a look here, probhably it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564796/max-file-number-can-php-upload-at-same-time

Comment: why did you declare `$pp1` and `$proof1` but didn't use it when moving the uploaded files?

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to upload multiple files simultaneously and have the information organized automatically in arrays for you. To do so, you need to use the same array submission syntax in the HTML form.

```
<input type="file" name="pp[]" placeholder="profile pic" />
<input type="file" name="pp[]" placeholder="id proof"/>
```

after form submission you can access each of them using

```
$name1 = $_FILES['pp']['name'][0];
$name2 = $_FILES['pp']['name'][1];
```